# Correctly addressing Intents to fix ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest, activitynotfoundexception

I get an ActivityNotFoundException when I use this code:

```
    public void addListenerOnButton3(){

    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {    
    Intent intentSettings = new Intent("net.stuffilike.kanaflash.Settings");
    showToast("Settings clicked,");
    try{
    startActivity(intentSettings); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        showToastL("Exception" + e);
    }
    return;
}
});
}
```

Fair enough, except I can't tell how it wants me to tell it where the Activity is.  Here is the relevant section of the Manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name="net.stuffilike.kanaflash.Settings"
        android:label="@string/settings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
```

How can I be sure the compiler finds my Settings.java file?
Oh, my package is named

```
package net.stuffilike.kanaflash;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {    
    Intent intentSettings = new Intent(X.this,Settings.class);
    showToast("Settings clicked,");
    try{
    startActivity(intentSettings); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        showToastL("Exception" + e);
    }
    return;
}
});
```

replace X with your current activity name ..

Answer (score 1):

The `constructor` for `new Intent(String action)` takes action as paramter.

As per your manifest, the action you are using is `android.intent.action.SETTINGS`,

1.So your Intent should be as below

```
Intent intentSettings = new Intent("android.intent.action.SETTINGS");
```

or

2.You can directly invoke the activity by using the Activity name,

```
Intent intentSettings = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
```

or

3.You can also define a custom action like `net.stuffilike.intent.action.SETTINGS` and then use this to create your `Intent` like

```
Intent intentSettings = new Intent("net.stuffilike.intent.action.SETTINGS");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways you can do this.

1. Use the action `String` to let the system see what `Activity`s can resolve the action on the `Intent`. If there is more than one `Activity` that can resolve the action, the user will get an option to pick which one they want.

   ```
   Intent intentSettings = new Intent("android.intent.action.SETTINGS");
   ```
2. Open the `Activity` using its class directly (can only be done if both `Activity`s are in the same app).

   ```
   Intent intentSettings = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
   ```